# MongoDB How to get users with Posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, web-deployment

I have a problem getting USERS with Posts

Schema of User and all related to it.

```
const answersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: String,
  code: String,
  postDate: String
});

const questionsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  code: String,
  postDate: String,
  answers: [answersSchema]

});

const blogpostsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  content:String,
  postDate: String

});
const clientSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  thumbnail: String,
  blogPosts: [blogpostsSchema],
  questions: [questionsSchema]
});

const Client = mongoose.model("Client",clientSchema);
const BlogPost= mongoose.model("BlogPost",blogpostsSchema);
const Answer = mongoose.model("Answer", answersSchema);
const Question =mongoose.model("Question",questionsSchema);
```

This is my query

```
Client.find({"blogPosts": {$exists: true}},function(err,foundUser){
    if (foundUser){
      console.log(foundUser)
      res.render("blog",{userWithPosts: foundUser,  clientStatus: clientStatus, logButton: logButton})
    } else {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    }


})
```

With this Query, there was a problem.

I want CLIENT Who has blogPosts,

how can I check whether the CLIENT has posts in blogPosts

Comment: {"blogPosts": {$exists: true, $ne: []}}

Comment: Thank You! It was helpful for many problems.